# How to create a new record for a has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a list of checkboxes where people can select one or more organizations for a project. It's a has many through association.

But I also want to add a text field that reads `Add Other` so the user can also create a new organization ***and assign it to the project automatically***.

**project.rb**

```
has_many :organizationables
has_many :organizations, through: :organizationables
attr_accessible :organization_ids
```

**organization.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :website
has_many :organizationables
has_many :projects, through: :organizationable
```

**organizationable.rb**

```
attr_accessible :organization_id, :project_id
belongs_to :organization
belongs_to :project
```

I know it's a weird name for the association 'organizationables` but oh well. I've tried different ways to setup the form but I can't make it work.

**The NEW PROJECT FORM is supposed to have checkboxes where organizations can be assigned to a project but will also have a `Other Organization` text field (which will create a New Organization and assign it to the project).**

Comment: Have you considered using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for this?

Comment: I'm using Simple Form but I don't know how to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: cocoon works with Simple Form (or Formtastic or standard forms) to do this - check it out.  And I think that a more legitimate name for your join model would be `Organizable`...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in one action you want to create the new organization and associate to an existing project, here's the easiest way:

```
new_organization.save!
project.organizations << new_organization
```

That will create and save the organizationable record linking the project with the new organization.

Update:

First save the new project. Then set up an array of organizations that they checked. If they created an organization, save it and add it to the array. Then to tie the list of the organizations to the project in one fell swoop:

```
project.organizations = my_list_of_checked_organizations
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association for a similar example.

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't update a `has_many :through` association, it's read only.

Comment: I want to create the new organization in the New Project form. they can use checkboxes to assign organizations to the project or they can fill in the `Other Organization` field (which would create a new organization)

Comment: Mauricio, my first example using '<<' absolutely works. Its effect on the database is to add records to the join table, not to the organizations table, but doing that adds to the project.organizations collection. Very simple and straightforward.